# Using RBF neural networks

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to run this code [LINK code ][1]on may laptop, I changed these package:

- from keras.engine.topology import Layer
- from tensorflow.keras.models import  load_model

to these package to work on my machine:

- from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer
- from tensorflow.python.keras.models import  load_model

and whenever I run a program, I get the log message:

```
2022-08-08 12:51:36.312596: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
2022-08-08 12:51:36.315077: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-Q4GR0LM
2022-08-08 12:51:36.315329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-Q4GR0LM
2022-08-08 12:51:36.315925: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\\RBF_neural_network_python-master\RBF_neuralNetwork .py", line 189, in <module>
    print(model.summary())
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2869, in summary
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling the model on a batch of data.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I've executed the code at the [repo](https://github.com/raaaouf/RBF_neural_network_python/) that you linked. It works fine on my end. I think the errors you are getting are coming from mixed imports of `tf.keras` and `tensorflow.python.keras`. You should really stick to the original imports `tensorflow.keras`.

From the comments you said that you are having problems with them. That is:

```
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved"
```

I suggest you to try creating a fresh environment.

**case 1)**
If you are using [anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), in your terminal do this:

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

**case 2)** If you are using a [pip venv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) with this:

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

In both cases the first instruction creates the environment and the second one activates it.

**case 3)** If you are not using any environment, uninstall tensorflow with:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

---

After that you can install Tensorflow. In my environment I have Tensorflow 2.7 and everything is working just fine, so I suggest you to do this:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
```

Then change the imports to the ones that you had before, and you should be ok.

**Update (the solution from the comments):**

The OP wasn't using any environment, so the solution was to simply uninstall tensorflow and install it again, but the gpu version this time with:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Sorry @claudia, Cold you see the Updated question, please?

Comment: Yes, commenting `model.summary()` you avoided the problem altogether but you did not fixed the problem. Try adding `model.build` as I show in the answer for keeping it. If that fixes it accept the answer and create a new question with the new error. From what I see the error seems unrelated and should have a separate question. @kayla

Comment: I should add model.build instead of model.summary() ? or?

Comment: See. First you do `model.build(input_shape=("your input shape"))` and then `print(model.summary())`. This way you are telling what is the input shape that is needed to create the summary. @Kayla

Comment: ("your input shape") this depends on what? and how can put the parameters to input_shape=?

Comment: You have to set the shape of your input, your x data. In your case I think it is `input_shape=(568,)`

Comment: Yes I thought that but I get on this 
shape=(self.output_dim, input_shape[1]),
IndexError: Exception encountered when calling layer "module_wrapper" (type ModuleWrapper).

tuple index out of range

Call arguments received by layer "module_wrapper" (type ModuleWrapper):
  � args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(568,), dtype=float32)',)
  � kwargs={'training': 'None'}
therefore I asked you.

Comment: Assuming that `X_train` is a numpy array, do `model.build(input_shape=X_train[0].shape)`. That should be the shape of your input @kayla

Comment: The same error!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue. See the guidelines of stackoverflow on [what to do when someone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @kayla